# Get contents of iframe in jquery and replace it to the parent html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, traversal

I am trying to get the entire contents from an iframe and replace it to the parent html. The sample code is as follows

```
 $('#textEditor').load(function(){
      var test = $('#textEditor').contents().find('html').html();
      alert(test);
      $('html').html(test); // Does not work in IE7
      $('body').html(test); // Works in IE7
    });
```

How do i access the html tag and write content to it in IE7 ??

```
$('html').html("asdfasdfsad"); // This doesnt work in IE7
```

Comment: i thin now you have two html tags in your page...so that might be causing the problem for 1st case

Comment: @Vivek No.. I am getting content starting from <head> so thats not the problem, it works perfectly in IE8 and other browsers except for IE7 :-(

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this isn't working in IE 7 but i can give you an alternativ solution. That would be to call the page via its url instead. So you replace your

```
var test = $('#textEditor').contents().find('html').html();
```

With the jquery for loading URL instead.

Comment: This is ofcourse if the problem indeed was to get the correct HTML from the iFrame? Or is the problem the inserting?